# Statistical test to determine if a variable is significantly positive or significantly negative?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, group-differences

Is there is a single statistical test I could do that would allow me to determine if a variable is significantly positive or significantly negative? By significantly positive or negative, I mean that the population mean is positive or negative.

The alternative to a single test, I'm guessing, is to do a 2-tailed t-test to see if the variable is different from 0, and then follow up with 1-tailed tests to see if it's greater or less than 0?

Comment: Why not just do a one tail test right-away?

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat you shouldn't perform a one tailed test unless you only expect deviations in one, pre-specified, direction.

Comment: Please say what you mean by 'significantly positive': population mean positive; population median positive; likely to produce more positive than negative outcomes (regardless of magnitude); stochastically dominates another variable, etc.

Comment: I meant population mean positive. Thanks for your suggestion -- I'll update the question.

Comment: @RyanVolpi Agreed. Isn't that what OP is talking about though? Maybe I missunderstood.

Comment: @TrynnaDoSta oh, you may be right! I didn't consider that interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply perform the two tailed T-test and then interpret the sign of the statistic as an indication of whether the mean is significantly greater or lesser than zero.

Comment: So I guess in that case, the p-value would also be indicative of the "strength" of the positivity/negativity?

Comment: The P-values is a function of the effect size *and* the variation in the data. But, with constant variation, the lower p-values would correlate with samples that are further from zero.

Comment: @RyanVolpi And a function of the sample size